# How do I avoid a type mismatch error when referring to the targe.value of a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I would appreciate help with the code below.

The debugger stops on `If target.Value <> "" Then` (first line of the bottom sub) and I suspect this is due to the fact that the target is a range with the potential for several target values. Is this line of thinking correct? If so, how do I go about solving this issue.

Note: 'FILLABLE_TOP_REG', 'CHK_PROD', & 'FILLABLE_BOT' are named ranges on sheet1 of my workbook.

Thank you!

If target.cells.count=1 And target.value <> ""...
For each cell in target...

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)

Dim TopREG_Range As Range

'PROMPTS USER TO CONFIRM CHANGE/DELETE
If Not Intersect(target, Range("FILLABLE_TOP_REG")) Is Nothing Then
    Call warning_msg(Range("H7"), target)
End If
If Not Intersect(target, Range("CHK_PROD")) Is Nothing Then
    Call warning_msg(Range("H7"), target)
End If
If Not Intersect(target, Range("FILLABLE_BOT")) Is Nothing Then
    Call warning_msg(Range("H" & target.Row), target)
End If
End Sub

Public Sub warning_msg(redirect As Range, target As Range)

If target.Value <> "" Then
            Dim Msg As String
                Msg = "Are you sure you want to delete and/or modify the following cell?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Selection.Address & "= " & Selection.Text
            Dim Ans As VbMsgBoxResult
                Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbCritical)
                Select Case Ans
            Case vbYes: Selection.ClearContents
            Case vbNo: redirect.Select
    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It depends. Do you want to process every cell if there is more than one changed, or do you only want to run this if a single cell changes?

Comment: I'd like to process when there is a singe cell changed in the range. Thanks JNevill.

Comment: Perfect, then I think your first idea would be the right way to go. `If target.cells.count=1 and target.value <> ""` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried If target.Cells.Count = 1 And target.Value <> "" Then
            Dim Msg As String... and I'm still getting a mismatch error u_u

Comment: Oh right.  Ok. First do the if statement for target.cells.count. then inside that do the second if for value. Sorry for the punctuation. On mobile now. :)

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much JNevill.